# create rtmp stream after approval in flash

Tags: php, red5

Is it possible to create a netstream after the user has approved to the use off the cam?
I ask this because i want to be able to detect if a user is actually transmitting so other people can see that their cam is on.
Right now the stream gets created after hitting play while approval has not be given yet.
Is it perhaps possible to send something along with hitting the allow/deny?

I'm using AS2 with RED5.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer:

```
Cam.onStatus = function(infoObj:Object) {
   switch (infoObj.code) {
      case 'Camera.Muted' :
         trace("Camera access is denied");
         break;
      case 'Camera.Unmuted' :
        send_data.camuser =user;
        send_data.camon = "PRIVATE";
        break;
   }
}
```